# reading file line by line and compare with shell array element : ksh

Tags: arrays, awk

I have an array of IDs and I want to print lines from a log file that match any value contained in the array. The input file format is given below, with the number that must match shown in bold.

> 2014-04-22 05:42:17|SPPEventQueue_skl0.cpp(449 )|**6**|CG |DEBUG|Executing
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|abc.cpp   (253 )|**6**|USR|INFO |IN  { Event::removeEvent
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|cax.cpp   (253 )|**5**|USR|INFO |removeEvent number = 46574731
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|zaw.cpp   (253 )|**7**|USR|INFO |Didn't find any Event.
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|asdf.cpp   (253 )|**3**|USR|INFO |OUT } Event
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|abcd.cpp(367 )|**8**|CG |DEBUG|op Event::Queue::publish, directly
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|efgh.cpp   (253 )|**11**|USR|INFO |IN  { Queue::Event
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|xyz.cpp   (253 )|**4**|USR|INFO |In removeEvent for eventNumber 46574731
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|Event.cpp(503 )|**6**|CG |DEBUG|op Queue::Event::removeEvent optimized,
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|form.cpp   (253 )|**1**|USR|INFO |IN  { Queue::EventQueue
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|service.cpp(1242)|**4**|P  |DEBUG|commitObject: Transaction 1285:5851 committed 
>   2014-04-22 05:42:17|form.cpp   (253 )|**6**|USR|INFO |removeEvent number = 46574731

The following code has one array to compare each elements at given file bold value in each line. It reads each line of the file, comparing the value shown in bold above with each element of the array. If a match is found, the line is stored in the output file. 
It is working fine but is taking a long time to read more than 10000 of lines and comparing with each array element.

```
while read -r line; do 
    typeset CURTHREADID=echo "$line" | cut -d "|" -f 3
    for index in ${THREADIDARR[@]}; do
      if [ $CURTHREADID == $index ]; then
            echo "$line" >> $OUTPUTFILE
            break
      fi
    done
done < $INPUTFILE
```

I have tried to write the same code using AWK but it is giving me an error and I don't know where I am failing. I need help to write same using AWK so I can speed up the output. Here is my attempt:

```
awk -v Thvar="$THREADIDARR" '
BEGIN{  command=cut -d "|" -f 3 }
{ CURTHREADID=getline | command
for(index in Thvar){
 if(CURTHREADID == Thvar[index]){print;break;}
}}' $INPUTFILE
```

Comment: helpful if you can post error

Comment: I have another file but line formate is different but need to impletment same with array and each line: Before I have line format as `2014-04-22 05:42:17|SPPEventQueue_skl0.cpp(449 )|6|CG |DEBUG|Executing` and coded as `"$line" | cut -d "|" -f 3`

Comment: It works with following answered. I have another file formate as given below `20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : **84**] . anything line` and I have tried with for loop and Array with below code `echo "$line" | cut -d " " -f 6 | cut -d "]" -f 1` can any one help me. So need to give nested splite inside the awk loop or can implement each line another way for coded `echo "$line" | cut -d " " -f 6 | cut -d "]" -f 1` . Can anyone help me .

Comment: I have added to my answer so that it works for your second type of file. In general, if you have another question you should ask it separately. Don't forget to accept an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
awk -va="${THREADIDARR[*]}" '
 {BEGIN {FS="|"; n=split(a,b," "); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) c[b[i]]=1}
 $3 in c {print}' $INPUTFILE
```

Comment: +1 Exactly. I like the fact we even both went for the same variable names!

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks :) I do not know kshell either, but I figured the solution did not depend on that.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm not very familiar with `ksh`, here's how I'd tackle the situation using `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' -v a="${THREADIDARR[*]}" '
BEGIN{
  split(a,b," ")
  for(i in b) c[b[i]] 
}
$3 in c' $INPUTFILE
```

This creates an array c, whose keys are the values of your input array. If the third column column of your input file is in those keys, then print the line (the default action).

---

**edit**: This might make it a bit quicker in `ksh`. I've removed the `echo` and `cut` parts:

```
#!/bin/ksh    

while read line; do
    IFS=\| read a b id c <<<$line
    for i in ${THREADIDARR[*]}; do
        if [ $i = $id ]; then
            echo "$line" >> $OUTPUTFILE
            break
        fi
    done
done < $INPUTFILE
```

---

**edit**: As for your second question, you could change your input field separator to `:` or `]` like this, leaving the rest of the code more or less the same:

`$INPUTFILE`:

```
20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : 1] . anything line
20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : 2] . anything line
20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : 3] . anything line
20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : 4] . anything line
20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : 5] . anything line
```

code:

```
THREADIDARR=(1 3)
awk -F": |]" -v a="${THREADIDARR[*]}" ' # two different field separators 
BEGIN{
  split(a,b," ")
  for(i in b) c[b[i]]
} 
$2 in c' $INPUTFILE # returns true (print) or false (don't print)
```

output:

```
20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : 1] . anything line
20140320 00:08:23.846 INFO [WebContainer : 3] . anything line
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, In second answer, only last array element compared with line and displayed. Suppose in array I have(4 11 and 7) then only lines with 7 only displayed. I think it is not comparing with 4 and 11 from array value with lines and parsing.

Comment: Thanks Håkon Hægland and Tom Fenech, both logics are working fine. 
But have problem if Will get any exception immediatelly after matching ThreadiD then those lines also required to display
Suppose matching thread ids are 1 and 3, then only exception after line thread 3 should display. after thread Id 5 is not required to display 

Need help for both files.